# S3 client initialization error via PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to initialize the S3 client from the AWS PHP SDK. My code is as follows:

```
$credentials = new Credentials(self::KEY, self::SECRET);

$s3_client = new S3Client([
    'version'     => 'latest',
    'region'      => $region,
    'credentials' => $credentials
]);
```

But am getting the following errors:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Argument 1 passed to Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient::__construct() must implement interface Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface, array given, called in /opt/showhouse/www/application/models/showhouse/common/services/aws/aws.php on line 47 and defined
>   Filename: Client/AbstractClient.php
>
> Line Number: 73

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Am using the latest version of the SDK installed via Composer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using AWS PHP SDK version 2.0. If so, then the S3Client indeed implements the AbstractClient class. This means that the parameters are:
    __construct( Aws\Common\Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface $credentials, Aws\Common\Aws\Common\Signature\SignatureInterface $signature, Guzzle\Common\Collection $config )

The S3Client implementation you are attempting to use is from version 3.0 of the AWS PHP SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation: Try using a downloaded zip file to install AWS SDK instead of Composer

I had the same problem when I used Composer to install AWS SDK because it appeared to be the recommended way in AWS documentation from the following URL.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html

But, after reading the helpful answer by Grilly, I decided to try using a downloaded zip file to install AWS SDK. The problem disappeared after I installed this way.

From a README file contained in the zip file, I could find a notification that the version of AWS SDK installed using the downloaded zip file was 3.0. Although I couldn't check version of AWS SDK installed using Composer because I couldn't find how, I am guessing that the version of AWS SDK installed using Composer was somewhat old enough to cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed by using PHP 5.6 with AWS SDK v3.x

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with credentials:
<?php

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
       'key'    => 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
       'secret' => 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
    )
));
```