# Credentials Error in Laravel for AWS/SDK Laravel PHP

Tags: laravel, amazon-ses, aws-php-sdk

I am using PHP 8.1.21 and Laravel 10.14.1 in a pretty simple setup. I've implemented AWS SES for outgoing email before with no trouble but in this case I get the following error:

```
Aws\Common\Client\AbstractClient::__construct(): Argument #1 ($credentials) must be of type Aws\Common\Credentials\CredentialsInterface, array given, called in /home/site/DOMAIN.COM/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php on line 252
```

I have AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION set in the .env and obviously the SDK installed. I am sending the email using a Laravel Notification that works flawlessly in the local server with Mailpit.

Any advice much appreciated.

Update: So it looks like this is because I have the aws-sdk-php 2.8 version. When I try and update it to 3.* though I get this error:

```
- aws/aws-sdk-php[3.0.1, ..., 3.3.4] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ~1.0 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.0.0, ..., 1.9.1] 
but the package is fixed to 2.5.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. 
Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
```

So far I can't get a set of dependencies that resolve.

Comment: Are you using the built-in SES support (i.e. `MAIL_MAILER=ses`) or something custom?

Comment: Does this answer your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33594052/s3-client-initialization-error-via-php-sdk

Comment: @ceejayoz Yep I am using the built-in SES support with both these set in .env MAIL_MAILER=ses, MAIL_DRIVER=ses. In my composer.json ai  I have require .. ."aws/aws-sdk-php": "^2.8" so I'll try and force V3.0 or download it and see.

Answer (score 2):

So I still don't know why the aws-sdk-php was installed at such an old version by Composer and I had to delete Guzzle to get it working by running the below. Guzzle version still the same as it was, but now it works:

`composer require "aws/aws-sdk-php:3.*" --update-with-all-dependencies`